# Android Странно выполняются потоки

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Пишу простенький кликер в андроид студио и столкнулся с проблемой, которая заключается в том, что при увеличении в отдельной активности(**ShopActivity**) переменной(**fonSum**), которая в фоне прибавляет число к балансу(и переменная и баланс находятся в **MainActivity**), поток вместо того, чтобы увеличивать и выводить новый баланс **раз** в секунду делает **N** выводов в секунду, где N = количеству улучшений fonSum. Прилагаю код обеих активностей:

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.clickerproject;

import androidx.annotation.MainThread;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static public float coinBalance = 0.0f;
    static public float coinsAdd = 1.0f;
    static public float fonSum = 1.0F;
    private float fromShop, fromShop1;

    boolean stopFlag = false;

    String coinBalanceString;
    String fonSumString;

    private float savedBalance;

    Button buttonAdd, openShop;
    public static TextView balanceText;

    SharedPreferences balanceSave;
    SharedPreferences fonSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadBalance();
        //loadFon();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        openShop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openShop);
        balanceText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.balanceText);
        Thread CoinThread = new CoinThread();
        CoinThread.start();
        Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(arguments != null){
            fromShop = arguments.getFloat("boost");
            //fonSum += fromShop;
            fromShop1 = arguments.getFloat("minusBalance");
            coinBalance -= fromShop1;
        }



       // stopFlag = false;

        if(CoinThread.isAlive()){
            Log.d("THREAD_CHECK", "Thread alive");
        }
        coinAdd();




    }

    /*public void endThread() {
        stopFlag = true;
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    /*Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
    int boost = (int) arguments.get("boost");
    fonSum += boost;*/

    class CoinThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fonSum += fromShop;
           Log.d("THREAD_CHECK", "Thread running");
            balanceText.setText(String.format("%.2f", coinBalance) + "");
            while(/*!stopFlag*/ true){

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    coinBalance += fonSum;

                    Log.d("THREAD_CHECK", "Coins added");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }




            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    balanceText.setText(String.format("%.2f", coinBalance) + "");
                    //balanceText.setText(String.format("%.2f", coinBalance) + "");
                }

            });
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        saveBalance();
        //endThread();
        //saveFon();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveBalance();
       //endThread();

        //saveFon();
    }

    void coinAdd() {
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                coinBalance += coinsAdd;
                balanceText.setText(String.format("%.2f", fonSum) + "");
            }
        });

        openShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShopActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                intent.putExtra("currentBalance", coinBalance);
            }
        });
    }







    void saveBalance() {
        balanceSave = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = balanceSave.edit();
        ed.putFloat(coinBalanceString, coinBalance);
        ed.commit();
    }

    void loadBalance(){
        balanceSave = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        float savedText = balanceSave.getFloat(coinBalanceString, 0.0f);
        Log.d("SaveLoadTest", "Loaded Successfully");
        coinBalance = savedText;
    }

    /*void saveFon() {
        fonSave = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed1 = fonSave.edit();
        ed1.putFloat(fonSumString, fonSum);
        ed1.commit();
    }

    void loadFon(){
        fonSave = getPreferences();
        float savedText1 = fonSave.getFloat(fonSumString, 0.0f);
        Log.d("SaveLoadTest", "FonSum loaded Successfully");
        fonSum = savedText1;
    }*/


}
```

**ShopActivity:**

```
package com.example.clickerproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.dynamicanimation.animation.SpringAnimation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    float localeBalance;
    float fonSum;

    Button firstTest, back;

   //Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, MainActivity.class);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);
        firstTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.testShop);
        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backFromShop);
        testShop();
        localeBalance = MainActivity.coinBalance;
        fonSum = MainActivity.fonSum;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    void testShop(){
        firstTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("BackTest", "CLICKED");
                float price = 10.0f;
                float value = 10.0f;
                /*if(MainActivity.coinBalance >= price){
                    MainActivity.coinBalance -= price;
                    MainActivity.coinsAdd += value;
                } else {
                    Toast alertToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Недостаточно средств!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    alertToast.show();
                }*/
                Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("boost", value);
                intent.putExtra("minusBalance", price);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    /*void backToMain(){
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("sum", 1);
                intent.putExtra("boost", 2);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }*/


    /*public void testShop(View view) {
        int price = 1;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sum", price);
        intent.putExtra("boost", 2);
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К счастью, потоки выполняются так, как и должны, но Вы ожидали иного...

Вот Вы запускаете новый поток каждый раз, когда создаётся активность:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    Thread CoinThread = new CoinThread();
    CoinThread.start();
    ...
    ...
```

А здесь Вы запускаете новую активность при нажатии на кнопку `firstTest`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("boost", value);
intent.putExtra("minusBalance", price);
startActivity(intent);
```

Таким образом Вы и создаёте **N** потоков при **N** покупках.

Я вижу такое решение Вашей проблемы: так как главная деятельность **`MainActivity`** не завершается, достаточно вернуться к ней, то есть вместо этого кода:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("boost", value);
intent.putExtra("minusBalance", price);
startActivity(intent);
```

написать этот:

```
finish();
```

Comment: А как в таком случае возможно передать переменные в главную активность? Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @galitred точно так же, как Вы их значения берёте из второй активности: `localeBalance = MainActivity.coinBalance;`, только, разумеется, необходимо им присвоить новые значения: `MainActivity.coinBalance -= price;`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!